# MongoDB createIndex not expiring data from collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to expire guest users after 1 hour of creation of the account. I looked up the MongoDB database as well as other similar questions and tried suggested solutions, but they also did not work.

When the guest user is created in the database ( it shows under `guests` collection in MongoDB Atlas so there is no problem with the way it is being created), it does not expire after 30 seconds.

Dependencies v:

- "mongoose": "^5.7.8",
- "node": "10.16.3"

This is the user.js where I save the user to the database, there is no issue with it:

```
router.post("/guest", function (req, res, next) {
    let guest = new Guest({
        email: req.body.email
    });

    guest.save(function (err) {
    });

    res.redirect('back');
});
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let guestSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true }
});

guestSchema.index({createdAt: 1},{expireAfterSeconds: 30});
module.exports = mongoose.model('guest', guestSchema);
```

So I also tried this:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let guestSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true }
});

guestSchema.createIndex({createdAt: 1},{expireAfterSeconds: 30});
module.exports = mongoose.model('guest', guestSchema);
```

Which results in an error `createIndex is not a function`.

I also tried this:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let guestSchema = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, required: true }
    expire: { type: Date, index: { expireAfterSeconds: 30 } }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('guest', guestSchema);
```

Unfortunately, neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents are not being expired because your `guestSchema` does not contain the `createdAt` field.

- The `guestSchema.index( ... )` definition is the [correct way](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) to define the TTL index. The index is saying to use the `createdAt` field, and to remove documents that are 30 seconds passed the `createdAt` value.
- However, a [document will not expire](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data) if it does not contain the field indexed by the TTL index.

Try adding the field `createdAt` to guestSchema, defining it as the date and time the user was created.

Comment: I added `createdAt: Date` to my `guestSchema` and `createdAt: Date.now()` to my guest route where I create the guest. It worked! Thank you!